# xlwings, jupyter notebook and Excel

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, xlwings

I am a big fan of xlwings and have normally used it to send data from jupyter to Excel. 
I would like the other way around and use the run main addin (v. 0.18) (not using any vba or macros) to run a jupyter notebook out of Excel. I have managed to run normal .py files with the quickstart myproject without any problems. Is it possible to run .ipynb files instead of .py files and if yes how?

Many thanks for your help

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the Jupyter API from your your `main()` function. Something like this:

```
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

def main():
    with open(notebook_filename) as f:
        nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
    ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
    ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
    with open('executed_notebook.ipynb', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        nbformat.write(nb, f)
```

See the [Jupyter docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-using-the-python-api-interface).